# How to change the color of the back button in a CupertinoNavigationBar in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-cupertino

I would like to change the color of the back button in my flutter app.

Here is what I have at the moment: [Screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4vwj.png)

I would like to change the color from light blu to white. I have searched online but found nothing. Here is my code (note my button is create automatically)

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
        heroTag: 'menupage',
        transitionBetweenRoutes: false,
        middle: Text(
          'Menu Page',
          style: kSendButtonTextStyle,
        ),
      ),
```

Many thanks in advance !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I resolved with setting the CupertinoTextThemeData...

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoApp(
      theme: CupertinoThemeData(
        primaryColor:
            Colors.white, //change color of the BOTTOM navbar icons when selected
        textTheme: CupertinoTextThemeData(
          primaryColor:
              Colors.white, //change color of the TOP navbar icon
```

Thanks Lucas for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

Example

[image]
[image]

`actionsForegroundColor: Colors.white`  in `CupertinoNavigationBar`

Do it

```
return  CupertinoPageScaffold(
      navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(actionsForegroundColor: Colors.white,
        heroTag: 'menupage',
        transitionBetweenRoutes: false,
        middle: Text(
          'Menu Page',
          style: TextStyle(),
        ),
      ), child: Text(''),
    );
```

Comment: thanks but it does not work for me. to clarify: I would like the blue arrow on the top bar to become white

Comment: this is what I read in the documentation: actionsForegroundColor → Color
Default color used for text and icons of the leading and trailing widgets in the navigation bar. [...]
@Deprecated('Use CupertinoTheme and primaryColor to propagate color'), final

Comment: Put `actionsForegroundColor: Colors.white` in `CupertinoNavigationBar`? This is to leave the white arrow

Comment: I did it but it does not change the color of the arrow. Could the problem be that my navBar is inside a cupertinoTabView and a CupertinoTabScaffold?

Comment: this not works for flutter 2.0, not such params in CupertinoNavigationBar

Comment: Wrap it in a `CupertinoTheme` and set the colors there.